# how can I fix this error when trying to install fpc with homebrew

Tags: homebrew, freepascal, brew-doctor

im trying to install fpc via homebrew
`brew install fpc`
but I got an error

`Warning: fpc 3.2.2_1 is already installed, it's just not linked. To link this version, run: brew link fpc`

```
and when I use that command I got another error
```

> `Error: Could not symlink bin/bin2obj
> Target /usr/local/bin/bin2obj
> already exists. You may want to remove it:
> rm '/usr/local/bin/bin2obj'
>
> To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
> brew link --overwrite fpc
>
> To list all files that would be deleted:
> brew link --overwrite --dry-run fpc

```
`

I then used the command to force the link and overwrite all conflicting files but another error came out
```

`

> Error: Could not symlink share/doc/fpc-3.2.2/aspell/examples/example.pas
> /usr/local/share/doc/fpc-3.2.2/aspell/examples is not writable.`

```
i also used brew doctor but I couldn't  solve what it told me
```

`

> Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
> If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
> building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected dylibs:
> /usr/local/lib/libpas2jslib.dylib
>
> Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
> Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause formulae that depend on
> those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
> fpc

```
`
```